# jquery: bind new dynamic element to function already defined

Tags: jquery, function, dynamic, bind

On my page I have

```
$(function()
{
  $('.load').click(function()
  { 
  var val =  $(this).attr('value'); //get value of the button that called this function
  //do stuff});
});
```

and some buttons defined on the initial html:

```
<input type="button" value="getData1" class="load" />
```

If I later add more buttons dinamically of the same class, and want them to operate the same way, how can I bind them to the original function?

I was looking at `.on` but it seems to define a NEW function. I'm hoping there is a way to use the one already defined.

Or should I define the function separately and call it from both places? If so, how can I pass the element that called the function as a parameter?

Any assistance will be much thanked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `on` is for, as you mentioned. On allows you to attach a listener to parts of the  document that contain the elements you want to monitor.

```
$(document).on('click', '.load', function() { 
    var val =  $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Using `document` isn't the best, so ideally you would put some selector in there that will match an element that surrounds all of your buttons, current and future.

Buttons that are added inside `document` after calling `on` will also trigger this handler even though they have been added later.

Comment: sweet! when you say "Using `document` isn't the best", is it related to the processing effort spent monitoring some areas of the document unnecessarily? or because it may bind elements not intended? or...?   Much thanks for your help!

Comment: @Henry It's no extra work when adding the event, but using `document` means that JS code will run every time you click anywhere on the page, and then it has to checkout if it matches `.load`. If you know all the buttons are inside something specific then it doesn't have to do any extra work if you click on other parts of the page.